# Angular 6 Unit testing: I want to stub a declared property for my test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I'm using angular version 6 and jasmine.

When I run ng test --sourceMap=false

**Error I get is: videojs is not defined**

I would like to stub videojs if possible.
Also, note that the component runs fine, its just the unit test that fails.

Videojs is an npm library I use for showing videos etc.

**My component that I'm testing:**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';

declare const videojs: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'test-details',
  templateUrl: './test-details.component.html'
})
export class TestDetailsComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  public videoJSplayer: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.initVideo();
  }

  public initVideo(): void {
    this.videoJSplayer = videojs(
      document.getElementById('video_player_id'),
      { controls: true, autoplay: false, preload: 'auto' }
    );
  }
}
```

**My Unit test**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TestDetailsComponent } from './test-details.component';

declare const videojs: any;

fdescribe('TestDetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: TestDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestDetailsComponent>;

  beforeEach(
    async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [],
        declarations: [ TestDetailsComponent ],
        schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
        providers: [
           { provide: videojs, useValue: {} }
        ]
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with @Ryan's answer as being a better approach, if you want to mock a global variable, you can just set the variable on the global scope in your spec. Because it's global scope, you'll want to be careful to clean it up after the test runs.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  global.videojs = {my: 'mock', object: 'here'};
});

afterEach(() => {
  delete global.videojs; // Cleanup
});
```

Side-note: You may use `window` instead of `global` if it suits your needs better.

Answer (score 2):

You could inject a service that has a reference to the videojs object/function instead of referencing it directly in the Component. Then you could mock the service in the test using provide/useClass, and put in whatever function/values for videojs that you want

Comment: I've updated my attempt. But still didnt work - could u edit my attempt above to what u mean please

Comment: I dont have a service for video js. I'm declaing videojs which is from an npm package called videojs. Video js works fine in the component / browser, I just need the test to run.

Comment: I'm just trying to mock this declare for the unit test: declare const videojs: any;